# Storing TimeZone and Currency for a User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, timezone, currency

We want to allow users to store their preference of Time Zone and Currency in the User settings.

We are using Rails 4 and MongoDB with MongoID. Is there any GEM that allows us to do it?

What datatype is best suited for storing them as all the time across the site displayed will have to be converted into the required timezone.

Comment: Why dont you store the preference for every user in the database?

Comment: @SampritiPanda thats the plan. what format is it usually stored in is the question.

Comment: Then have a look at the https://github.com/sporkd/mongoid-metastamp gem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using [Rails time zones](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html), then you would store the identifier associated with that time zone.  For example "Eastern Time (US & Canada)".  However, I don't recommend that you use Rails time zones, for the reasons outlined in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) (near the bottom).

Instead, you should probably use the [tzinfo gem](http://tzinfo.github.io/), which uses standardized time zones from the IANA/Olson data.  For example, "America/New_York".

Currency is best stored as three-letter [ISO 4217 currency code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217).  For example "USD" or "EUR".

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your recommendation not to use Rails time zones if you're only using them within Rails. Rails does in fact use tzinfo, and if you need to interface with other libraries, Rails will retrieve standardized time zone names given its "friendly" names.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser - The main complaint is that it is an arbitrary subset.  I asked about it [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4416549), and got little info other than that it was an accident of history because Rails time zones came first and then were mapped to tzinfo zones later.

Comment: Another complaint is that the names are friendly only for English speakers, where IANA tz id's are considered canonical - leaving localizations to other projects, such as [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/).

Comment: Rails i18n doesn't provide time zone names in other languages (as it does for AR errors)? I don't know. Of course, either sort of time zone name could easily be used as a translatable string for an i18n library.

Comment: If you store the IANA versions instead of the Rails version, you can do time zone related queries in your database much more efficiently. PostgreSQL, for example, has IANA time zone conversion built in.